# found a virtual manifest at <path> instead of a package manifest

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I searched for `[rust] "instead of a package manifest"` on this site before asking and found no hits. I also read about virtual manifests [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html) but did not resolve my question.

My goal is to make changes to [azul](https://github.com/maps4print/azul).

To achieve this I read about patching dependencies [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#overriding-repository-url), and now I have this `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "my_first_azul_app"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Name <Email>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
azul = { git = "https://github.com/maps4print/azul" }

[patch."https://github.com/maps4print/azul"]
azul = { path = "../azul" }
```

In path `../azul` I have checked out the azul project with `git clone`. In `main.rs` I have followed [this](https://github.com/maps4print/azul/wiki/Installation#adding-azul-to-your-dependencies) to get,

```
extern crate azul;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

Then I try to test

```
$ cargo run
error: failed to resolve patches for `https://github.com/maps4print/azul`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for a dependency on `azul`

Caused by:
  Unable to update /home/name/projects/azul

Caused by:
  found a virtual manifest at `/home/name/projects/azul/Cargo.toml` instead of a package manifest
```

I do not understand the final caused by line.
If I remove the `[patch]` configuration, it "works".
Quoting because it fails to compile, but that is why I am trying to check it out and attempt a fix. What charges do I need to make to develop the `azul` dependency?

TIA,

Answer (score 20):

looks like azul is using workspaces so if you want to refer to it via path you must point to the exact member(s) of that workspace.

azul's Cargo.toml contains

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "cargo/azul",
    "cargo/azul-css",
    "cargo/azul-core",
    "cargo/azul-layout",
    "cargo/azul-text-layout",
    "cargo/azul-widgets",
    "cargo/azul-css-parser",
    "cargo/azul-native-style",
]
```

so I believe you should be able to do something like:

```
[dependencies]
azul = { path = "../azul/cargo/azul"
azul-css = { path = "../azul/cargo/azul-css" }
```

you may need all/some of the members there.

Answer (score 8):

For those who come to this question because they tried `cargo install` and got the error message:

```bash
$ cargo install                            
error: found a virtual manifest at `~/nextclade/Cargo.toml` instead of a package manifest
```

The solution is as simple as adding `--path <executable-sub-cratepath>`:

```bash
$ cargo install --path packages_rs/nextclade-cli                         
error: found a virtual manifest at `~/nextclade/Cargo.toml` instead of a package manifest
```

For a workspace structured like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
└── packages_rs
   ├── nextclade
      └── Cargo.toml
   ├── nextclade-cli
      └── Cargo.toml
   └── nextclade-web
      └── Cargo.toml
```

This is tracked in https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7599